# How to delete all voice mail?

Tags: google-voice

I'm trying to delete all 500+ voicemails in Google Voice. The query `in:voicemail is:unread` seems return a promising list, but it only shows the first 10.

How can I delete them all at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, unlike Gmail, when you use the "Select All" checkbox and you have multiple pages of results, you *don't* get the "10 messages selected, click here to select all 501" (paraphrased) link.

I'm afraid your only option is to delete them 1 page at a time.

There looks like there *should* be some [keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/voice/answer/117493) that would help make this process less painful (`*` then `a` to select all messages, `#` to send to Trash) but they didn't work for me.

Google Voice is not a fully-baked product. I'm afraid it just doesn't have the features we have come to expect from Google.

Comment: I don't have a ten key, but those shortcuts didn't work for me. Had go into FPS mode with the mouse